# Error to execute Feature file in new directory

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

My file worked normally when it was java in the following structure `src \ test \ java \ login.feature`. When creating a folder with the name of feature staying in the following structure `src / test / java / feature / Login.feature` it does not execute.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/java/feature"},
plugin = {"json:target/cucumber.jason"},
glue = "src/test/java")

public class Runner {

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the below line

```
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/java/feature"},
```

to as shown below

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/feature/",
```

Comment: `features` is a `String[]` in `CucumberOptions` - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/58a2622604a523977e05a792d1d45af20cd6cc2a/core/src/test/java/io/cucumber/core/options/CucumberOptions.java#L18. Both the syntax are valid.

Comment: I believe it is not a problem at cucumber or Runner. This happened after I created the new features directory and moved my feature file into it !. It will be that it is not in java that we need to modify the reference of this file. See my new image Please.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a rather old version of Cucumber. Its path scanning is less then ideal.

Aside from upgrading it is recommended that you use the standard maven layout for your project. This means that feature files are resources that should be placed in the resources directory. For example:

```
|- src/main/java/com/example
| |- App.java
|- src/test/java/com/example
| |- StepDefinitions.java
| |- RunCucumberTest.java
|- src/test/resource/com/example/
| |- single.feature
| |- rule.feature
| |- outline.feature
```

This allows you to use class path uris for features and package names for the glue.

```
@CucumberOptions(
  features = {"classpath:com/example"},
  glue = "com.example"
)
```

And when using this layout in later versions of Cucumber you can also omit the the `features` and `glue` from `CucumberOptions` because Cucumber will search to the package of the `RunCucumberTest` class for glue and features by default.

Comment: I believe it is not a problem at cucumber or Runner. This happened after I created the new features directory and moved my feature file into it !. It will be that it is not in java that we need to modify the reference of this file.

Comment: See the new Image, please!.

Comment: My solution was: rename the Login.feature file to loginGmail.feature, this done it executed. src/test/java/feature\ loginGmail.feature